# Alternative to fancybox?

Tags: asp.net, fancybox

The site I am working on was using a fancybox to display checkboxes and such so that an admin can easily add more items to a specific product. After messing with it for way too long, I have to scrap that fancybox, but now that the page is broken, I'm not sure what to do. The checkboxes that were displayed are in such a large quantity that using collapsible divs would just make the page a huge mess.

Is there a different modal pop-up that might work better than fancybox? I read that modals just don't work with ASP and that is what I am using for this site. ASP.net 4.0 using VB. If anyone has ideas or suggestions I would love to hear them. I'm struggling with where to take this project now.

Comment: What problem were you having with FancyBox? Couldn't you put the checkboxes inside an accordion?

Comment: The submit buttons in my pop ups wouldn't work. I used a tweak I found online to fix it, but it still didn't work with checkboxes and textareas. It only worked with one of my modals.

Comment: maybe you need to apply any javascript functions to the buttons inside Fancybox using the `onComplete` callback?

Answer (score 4):

There are hundreds of jQuery plugins with modal windows and close functionality. For example check [this](http://choosedaily.com/1178/15-jquery-popup-modal-dialog-plugins-tutorials/) . I personally use [colorbox](http://colorpowered.com/colorbox/)

Comment: I was looking at that SimpleModal yesterday. I just want to be sure that it will actually get along with ASP. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: Your ASP.NET is primarily code behind. Any jQuery/javascript modal popup goodness will not interfere if implemented properly. It's completely client side where your .net is server side. Just make sure you implement clean code, and you'll be good to go.

Comment: and colorbox is open source under MIT